# What are the names of the pieces of a question mark?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, typography

A question mark `?` seems to be composed of two distinct pieces, top and bottom.  Do these pieces have their own names, and if so, what are they?

Comment: Another question I've had but never thought about.  +1

Comment: I would use [Upper Case and Lower Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Serriffe).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're willing to go entirely by [hearsay](http://ilovetypography.com/2008/03/27/extreme-type-terminology-part-2/), a question mark has a curl, a lobe and a ball.

To quote:

> Just as Kinky Friedman anthropomorphizes this B, giving it human
> characteristics, namely ribs, type designers have come up with some
> very human terms to describe the details of the letterforms that they
> create. They speak the arm (of, say, an E), the crotch (of an M),
> which could further be described as an acute crotch or an obtuse
> crotch, the ear (of some g’s), which might be a flat ear or a floppy
> ear, the eye (of an e), the leg (of a k), the shoulder (of an n), the
> tail (of a j or a Q), and the spine (of an S). **There is a sketch by
> the great type designer Ed Benguiat that labels the curl, the lobe and
> the ball of a single question mark.**

It's hearsay because I couldn't find a picture of Ed Benguiat's sketch, but if the linked blog is quoting reliably, then I would say this is a fair answer since Ed Benguiat is unquestionably an important expert in typeface design.

Comment: Nice. I think your answer could be improved with a blockquote from your interesting link.

Comment: Thank you @Callithumpian.  That is an excellent suggestion.  I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: "Kinky Friedman". Best freaking name ever. XD

Comment: The ball is obvious, but which part is the _curl_ and which the _lobe_?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I looked everywhere (i.e. Google) for the sketch mentioned in the quote, but couldn't find it.  I'm guessing, but I would say the curl is the top of the main part of the question mark and the lobe is the bottom of the main part.  In serif fonts particularly the bottom of the main part curls around like an ear lobe.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any common typographical terminology for the top part so you could call the top bit:

- top part,
- squiggle,
- curl,
- curve,
- stroke.

You could call the bottom bit:

- bottom part,
- dot,
- jot,
- tittle,
- period,
- full stop.

A [tittle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tittle) is a small distinguishing mark, such as diacritic or the dot in the letter *i* and *j*, so I propose the terms **squiggle and tittle**.

Comment: +1 Wikipedia uses the _["stroke-over-dot"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark#History)_ combo.

Answer (score 1):

In *The elements of typographic style* by Robert Bringhurst, they are referred to as a **hook / crook** and a **dot**.

Comment: Hook, crook and a dot is preferable to "obtuse crotch", but that's merely my personal preference ;o)