# Is there an alternative, one-word name for the question mark?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, punctuation, synonyms, typography

Is there an alternative name for the question mark?  For example, the exclamation point is often called a *bang*, the number symbol is an *octothorpe* and is often referred to as a *pound sign*, *sharp symbol*, or *hash mark* due to  it’s use in specific subjects (currency, music, and social media, respectively) and the asterisk symbol is often called a *star*.

Is there such an alternative name for the question mark whether it be slang or otherwise?

Comment: Note that "bang" is a very colloquial word -- you shouldn't use it in any remotely formal writing -- and I don't think it's widely recognized. "Star" for asterisk is pretty common. I wouldn't use it in a scholarly paper, but it would probably be acceptable in, say, a a magazine article. We'll see what answers you get on question mark, but I don't think there's any other word that would be accepted in formal writing.

Comment: I remember from copy-editing days that we called it "query," especially when speaking with a compositor.

Comment: Related: _[What are the names of the pieces of a question mark?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/43539/5822)_

Comment: I prefer "shriek" for the exclamation mark.  I've heard/seen the question mark referred to as "the interrogatory".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is "query".

Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. query, *n* 2:

> A question mark (?), used in writing to indicate a degree of doubt about the accuracy or validity of a following (occas., a preceding) word or statement. Also used in speech to express a written question mark of this kind. Cf. qy. int.

Comment: Actually, per other answers, there ***is*** *one exact word*: eroteme.  Pardon the 'attack', but it's good to note this here, since the accepted answer could be considered not the correct answer.  Particularly, 'query' refers to a mid-sentence `?` whereas 'eroteme' is the punctuation at the end.

Answer (score 12):

Programmers have been known to call it ‘hook’.

---

Modern programmers have a lot more hooky things to cope with than just the old `QUESTION MARK` from antediluvian typewriter keyboards.  For example, here are a bunch of characters whose names contain ‘question’, or ‘glottal’, or ‘hook’, or ‘interro’:

| Code | chr | GenCat | Script | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U+003F | ? | GC=Po | SC=Common | QUESTION MARK |
| U+00BF | ¿ | GC=Po | SC=Common | INVERTED QUESTION MARK |
| U+01BE | ƾ | GC=Ll | SC=Latin | LATIN LETTER INVERTED GLOTTAL STOP WITH STROKE |
| U+0241 | Ɂ | GC=Lu | SC=Latin | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER GLOTTAL STOP |
| U+0242 | ɂ | GC=Ll | SC=Latin | LATIN SMALL LETTER GLOTTAL STOP |
| U+0294 | ʔ | GC=Lo | SC=Latin | LATIN LETTER GLOTTAL STOP |
| U+0296 | ʖ | GC=Ll | SC=Latin | LATIN LETTER INVERTED GLOTTAL STOP |
| U+02A1 | ʡ | GC=Ll | SC=Latin | LATIN LETTER GLOTTAL STOP WITH STROKE |
| U+02A2 | ʢ | GC=Ll | SC=Latin | LATIN LETTER REVERSED GLOTTAL STOP WITH STROKE |
| U+02C0 | ˀ | GC=Lm | SC=Common | MODIFIER LETTER GLOTTAL STOP |
| U+02C1 | ˁ | GC=Lm | SC=Common | MODIFIER LETTER REVERSED GLOTTAL STOP |
| U+02DE | ˞ | GC=Sk | SC=Common | MODIFIER LETTER RHOTIC HOOK |
| U+02E4 | ˤ | GC=Lm | SC=Latin | MODIFIER LETTER SMALL REVERSED GLOTTAL STOP |
| U+0309 | ◌̉ | GC=Mn | SC=Inherited | COMBINING HOOK ABOVE |
| U+0321 | ◌̡ | GC=Mn | SC=Inherited | COMBINING PALATALIZED HOOK BELOW |
| U+0322 | ◌̢ | GC=Mn | SC=Inherited | COMBINING RETROFLEX HOOK BELOW |
| U+061F | ‭ ؟ | GC=Po | SC=Common | ARABIC QUESTION MARK |
| U+097D | ॽ | GC=Lo | SC=Devanagari | DEVANAGARI LETTER GLOTTAL STOP |
| U+203D | ‽ | GC=Po | SC=Common | INTERROBANG |
| U+2047 | ⁇ | GC=Po | SC=Common | DOUBLE QUESTION MARK |
| U+2048 | ⁈ | GC=Po | SC=Common | QUESTION EXCLAMATION MARK |
| U+2049 | ⁉ | GC=Po | SC=Common | EXCLAMATION QUESTION MARK |
| U+2E18 | ⸘ | GC=Po | SC=Common | INVERTED INTERROBANG |
| U+2E2E | ⸮ | GC=Po | SC=Common | REVERSED QUESTION MARK |
| U+FE16 | ︖ | GC=Po | SC=Common | PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL QUESTION MARK |
| U+FE56 | ﹖ | GC=Po | SC=Common | SMALL QUESTION MARK |
| U+FF1F | ？ | GC=Po | SC=Common | FULLWIDTH QUESTION MARK |

Now that characters have official names that are so tediously long, like `LATIN LETTER INVERTED GLOTTAL STOP WITH STROKE`, it’s even more likely that short slangy forms will get used, although probably only locally.

Comment: "Hook" jumped to mind as something I may have heard/imagined, but I couldn't find any other reference to it. As a programmer, I've used "bang" for "!" and "pound", "sharp", or "hash" for "#", but I've never used "hook" for "?".

Comment: Although it has been mentioned that the "hook" is the inverted question mark, I see to also recall hearing this symbol being called a hook a long time ago.  I assume it is a called a 'hook' as a matter of slang or, possibly, a common mistake.  This answer is sufficient for my needs.  Thank you.

Comment: You'll occasionally find old BASIC programmers who refer to it as "print" since it was frequently used as an abbreviation for that.

    10 ? "Hello World"
    20 GOTO 10

Comment: @tchrist A lot of the marks that you refer to are "glottal stops". While these share some physical characteristics with a question mark, they are functionally nothing like question marks. Glottal stops are [a type of consonantal sound used in many spoken languages produced by obstructing airflow in the vocal tract.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop) and not punctuation marks like those that are listed.

Comment: @GeoGriffin Yes, of course. You can tell that by examining their respective general categories.  Only those with `GC=Po` are punctuation *per se*. People kept mentioning other things that look like they should be called *hooks*, so I tried to elaborate many others that could be reasonably called such. I forgot to mention `LATIN SMALL LETTER R WITH FISHHOOK` U+027E “ɾ” or all the rest of the fishhook letters. There are three fishy *emoji*, too: `FISH` U+1F41F  ; `TROPICAL FISH` U+1F420  ; and `BLOWFISH` U+1F421  . No hooks there, though. ☺ Esh ʃ, & integrals like ∫&∰ are kinda hooky, too.

Comment: @SeanDuggan It's another matter that in BASIC, "?" really sent the output to the console not the printer.

Comment: @Kris
^_^ At least unless you redirected it. ? #1 "Hello World" would go to the printer on my CoCo if I'm remembering correctly. Higher numbers covered everything from file output to other devices.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Bringhurst mentions on p. 309 of *The Elements of Typographic Style* v3.2 that `!` is sometimes called a “screamer” by British typographers; that reminds me how at my university (Madison, Wisconsin) we always called it a “shriek”, back before “bang” became popular in ᴜᴜᴄᴘ paths, like `...!{allegra,heurikon,ihnp4,seismo,uwm-evax}!uwvax!tom`, which was my old email address back in the early 80s.

Comment: I'm a programmer who was looking for a word to use in code since `?` isn't valid in a name... this is perfect.

Answer (score 9):

I am a fan of Asterix (also Obelix), and what you should call * is asterisk. :)

It is called star because it looks like one, and also aster- is a Latin root for star, viz. astral, astronomy, astronaut, astrology etc. So, in essence it is just a formal name of the same sense of a term.

As for ?, you can call it **interrogation point, interrogation mark, question point, query or eroteme**  Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark

Hook should be more appropriate for the inverted '?'.

Comment: +1 for Hook should be more appropriate for the inverted '?'.

Comment: Fun fact: *obelisk* is another name for *dagger* †.

Answer (score 2):

[source](http://catb.org/jargon/html/A/ASCII.html)

> ?
>   Common: query; ; ques . Rare: quiz; whatmark; [what]; wildchar; huh; hook; buttonhook; hunchback.

[source](http://ascii-table.com/pronunciation-guide.php)

> **question mark**
>   question, query, whatmark, what, wildchar (UNIX), huh, ques, kwes, quiz, quark, hook, scroll (NetHack), interrogation point

Comment: The ASCII list is a nice page to bookmark.  "Huh" is an interesting one.  I don't think I could ever get myself to call a question mark a "huh".

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a **question mark** referred as anything else, with the possible exception of just **question** (dropping the **mark**)

The Jargon File has a nice description for [bang](http://catb.org/jargon/html/B/bang.html) and [Computer keyboard key explanations](http://www.computerhope.com/keys.htm) references all the other marks that you talk about, but nothing for **question mark**.

Answer (score 0):

Some symbols, such as question mark and comma, are read by simply stating their names, whereas other symbols, such as ampersand and apostrophe, have a separate reading ("and", and "prime", respectively, in this case).

Answer (score 0):

> erotem: noun; The symbol used in writing known as a question mark...?

This is my resource: http://english-grammar-mistakes.blogspot.com/2008/03/read-and-read.html

Although I searched the word online, I only found variations of it. I found no other sites to back up the claim that *erotem* is a synonym for *question mark*.